# Text to the right after blinking cursor inside input tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know what to search for. But I want to style my input first of all it display a help text with placeholder for example:

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" placeholder="Enter your blog domain" type="text">
```

Edit: But when the user click on it and enter a value I want to display .domain.com right after the blinking cursor. How could I do that?

Comment: so when the user click in the input field, ".domain.com" should be displayed in the input field, right?

Comment: @Thinker Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Also, this value should sent to the server or just in the UI?

Comment: @MoshFeu Just the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) for your purpose.

```
$(".input-lg").click(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
       $(".input-lg").val(".domain.com");
    $(".input-lg")[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0);
});
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/wr9tdzxr/)

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT:**
You need to check the field to make sure you don't overwrite the input field existing data every time the field is clicked.

Comment: Thank you man, really helped med out. Just one question, could I add one more javascript function to it so that when the user have entered and the input field is no longer selected, I can do all the text combined centered in the field? That would be cool!